# scroll list view Text view item inside list view position change and list view item return duplicate also

Tags: android, performance, listview

```
//********* base adapter *****
```

Listview inside Button click to set the value inside TextView but text view duplicate values return and when I scroll TextView position change I have attached my base adapter code kindly help to solve.

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class listadapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;

    ArrayList<Listdata> listitem;



    public  listadapter(Context context, ArrayList<Listdata> listitem) {
            this.context = context;
            this.listitem = listitem;
        }

        /*private view holder class*/
        public class ViewHolder {

            TextView itemname;

            TextView itemrate;

            TextView itemcount;

            TextView itemtotal;


            Button add;

            Button sub;


        }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listitem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listitem.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listitem.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         final ViewHolder holder ;

            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.itemname=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemname);

            holder.itemrate=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemrate);

            holder.itemcount=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.count);

            holder.itemtotal=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.total);

            holder.add=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.add);

            holder.sub=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.minus);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

            }
            else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


            Listdata ld=(Listdata) getItem(position);

            holder.itemname.setText(ld.getItemname());

            int a=ld.getItemrate();

            holder.itemrate.setText(Integer.toString(a));

            holder.add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override

                public void onClick(View v) {


                       Listdata ld=listitem.get(position);

                       ld.itemcount++;


                       holder.itemcount.setText(String.valueOf(ld.itemcount));

                }
            });



            holder.sub.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {



                }
            });



        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your actual problem what you expect and what you got ? please be more specific.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that this question, if it is a question, is not the sort of question that belongs on this site. We like clear, specific questions about specific programming problems. I encourage you to look around the site at some other questions with a lot of up-votes in order to get a better sense of what this site is all about.

Comment: thanks for your reply i have issue in text view  and button inside list view,when scroll list view text view position change and duplicate values return after override following method its solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solve the problem 
Override this method

```
@Override
  public int getViewTypeCount() {

   return getCount();
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {

   return position;
  }
```